# what is file: in sdcard AVD creation

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

while creating AVD what is the use of File: in SDcard generally we will choose `size:`

what is `file:`

[image]

Comment: It mite be use a file to save sdcard info and other data info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is option is for using an existing SD card file, if you have one. For example, you can create two emulators sharing an SD card image. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This input requites the path of the file which is made by tool **mksdcard** which is used to create a blank FAT32 image to be used with the Android emulator. This file will be mounted in emulator as external media storage.

Comment: do u know how to insert sdcard thru terminal?